# Is it possible to concatenate two strings in soy (Closure Templates)?

Tags: templates, closures, google-closure-templates

With soy, I would like to concatenate two strings (hard-coded or variables) into one. My idea was to "parametrize" the first variable with the second:

`{let $key: 'abc_$anothervariable' /}`

This doesn't work. I also tried using builtin `join()` function for lists:

`{let $key: join(['abc', $anothervariable], '') /}`

But this approach doesn't work either - it even seems to have invalid syntax. Is it even possible to do something like that in Closure Templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer actually turned out to be as easy as:

`{let $key: 'abc_' + $anothervariable /}`